# Selecting closest class and removing it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When user clicks on "edit" how can I find closest `row_form` and remove it with jquery?
Here is what I tried so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gv2g1dq/)
**HTML**

```
<div id="settings_wrapper">
        <h1>General settings</h1>
        <div class="settings_row">
          <span class="row_name">Name</span>
          <div class="row_edit"><p class="row_edit_button">Edit</p></div>
          <div class="row_form">
            <form action="this.php"><span>New name:</span><input type="text" /><input type="submit" value="Save"><span>New name:</span><input type="text" /></form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="settings_row">
          <span class="row_name">Name</span>
          <div class="row_edit"><p class="row_edit_button">Edit</p></div>
          <div class="row_form">
            <form action="this.php"><span>New name:</span><input type="text" /><input type="submit" value="Save"><span>New name:</span><input type="text" /></form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".row_edit_button").click(function(){
         $(this).closest(".row_form").remove(); 
      });
});
```

Comment: Jquery `closest` function *get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree*. In the html you posted, element with class `row_form` is not an ancestor of the edit button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target element is the next sibling of the `parentNode` of the clicked element. `closest` selects the closest matching *parent* element. One option is:

```
$(".row_edit_button").click(function() {
   $(this.parentNode).siblings(".row_form").remove(); 
});
```

Other options are:

```
$(this).parent().next(".row_form").remove();
$(this).closest('.settings_row').find(".row_form").remove();
```